# Do not kill the process immediately when aborted in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is there any way to increase the timeout before killing the process when jenkin job is aborted.

When i kill a job, i see the below message "After 20s process did not stop" and it kills immediately, i would like to increase timeout of 20s to 20m.

Comment: How do you kill the job? Can you add some code? Is a force-kill a solution maybe?

Comment: I am just clicking "x"(cancel) button in jenkin job. Its just a normal jenkins pipeline job.

Comment: @louis what are your findings later? Are you able to increase this 20s timeout?

Comment: @merlachandra sadly No, I have handled in the scripts to exit immediately when SIGTERM is detected. I did not get the way to increase from Jenkins